# Angualar , NodeJs and Mysql

Tags: mysql, angular, express

Apparently am new to Angular, I have been codding projects from scratch full stack with PHP. 
I decided to dive into a framework and I chose angular then Express for for APIs; databases will be MYSQL.
Now, am having trouble in connecting all these together since i have been using local-host (WAMP) always.

Kindly assist on how to connect all of them.
thanks....

Comment: Typo there, I meant Angular

Comment: What do you mean by connecting them?

Comment: @RonRofe I mean bringing them to work together. Am converting an application that I had engineered with just PHP files. PHP file would just connect to the database, do the querying and results rendered back just that simply. But How do i implement the same path in Angualr for front end and Express to Handle the back end? Also, where will I store the database now that am not using my WAMP anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking to connect everything together by using HTTP or HTTPS.
Your backend (node + express) exposes multiple routes (urls) that then trigger controllers, wich then respond to the http request.

In angular you can make these http requests using the httpclient: [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)
You make these requests to the url of your express app. For example if it running on your machine and on port 3000 (usually used for node apps) then you make a request to `http://localhost:3000/<route>`.

In angular you usually use one or more services for the HTTP requests. That way you can reuse your code in multiple components or save requests by saving values inside the service and then retrieving the value from the service instead of making a new HTTP request. Here you can read more about services in Angular: [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services).

Keep in mind, that the Angular application is running in the clients browser. So when you deploy your app later, then you need to make requests to the backends url or ip. Also you need to make sure, that the backends port is available from that client. You can use the environments for that in angular, there you can set enviroment variables. When you later build your application with the `--prod` flag: `ng build --prod` then angular will use the production environment variables instead of the non production ones. More on that here: [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/build)

Comment: Kruger, thank you so much. It seems I just need to get familiar with Angular first.

Comment: I really can recommend you this guide for the angular http part: [Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/). It covers almost all major concepts needed for angular HTTP, including some bonus ones. For example HTTP Interceptors, wich are used to intercept the http request before it leaves to the backend or enters into the service. That is for example very useful if you want to add a Auth-Header to every request to the backend or do retries upon certain fail conditions.

Comment: Kruger, where will the database reside now and how will i access it?

Comment: You would do all the database interaction in your backend (Node/Express App).
You would either want a ORM, for example [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) or you would need a database driver, if you want to write plain SQL. For example: [MySQL NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). Then you would create controllers that use these database drivers and respond with the needed data (usually as json). Then you would want to create a route, that maps the controller / controller function to a URL. This would then be accessed by Angular.